# How to extract byteStream from Surfaceview while recording video

Tags: android, video-streaming, surfaceview, mediarecorder

I am trying to create an android app which extracts the bytestream from the live video feed and then transfers that bytestream through a service that I created to another device.Having spent a lot of time searching for the solution for my query I still haven't found a solution.I tried using MediaRecorder using LocalSocket but it did not solve my issue